# Compile MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, monomac

How can I setup MonoMac and Xamarin Mac to be compiled in Visual Studio as it is for MonoTouch? In this case I am just building libraries that are pure Mono (but do refer to the MonoMac.AppKit and .Foundation.

The ultimate goal is to get TeamCity to call Visual Studio and compile the library for Mac in addition to Windows, Android and iOS. But all from the PC as buildAgent (connected to a Mac for the Xamarin facilitated compile).

I don't even need to Debug, just do the final compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just building a library you should be able to copy Xamarin.Mac.dll or MonoMac.dll to your windows machine and reference it in your library project.

Finally just reference the library you just built in your Xamarin.Mac/MonoMac project on the Mac.

Comment: Hello Rolf Bjarne Kvinge , Can you kindly say where we can find MonoMac.dll to download ?

Comment: @manuthalasseril: build your project for distribution on your Mac, and it should end up next to your executable.